# Understanding Covariance Example

Tags: scala, covariance

[Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/) presents this example on co-variance.

Define a class `T` with a co-variant parameter. Co-variant means that instantiating a `T[+A]` is legal provided the parameter is a sub-type or equal to `A`'s type.

```
scala> class T[+A] {}
defined class T
```

Instantiate a `T[...]` with `AnyRef`.

```
scala> val x = new T[AnyRef]
x: T[AnyRef] = T@11e55d39
```

Then, assign `x` to a `T[Any]`. `Any` is the parent of `AnyRef`.

As a result, we can create a `T[Any]` with a `T[AnyRef]` since `AnyRef` is a sub-type of `Any`.

```
scala> val y : T[Any] = x
y: T[Any] = T@11e55d39
```

However, we can't do the same with `T[String]` since `Any` is **not** a sub-type of `String.

```
scala> val z : T[String] = x
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
found : T[AnyRef]
required: T[String]
val z : T[String] = x
```

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Covariance (`T[+A]`): `A` is subtype of `B` => `T[A]` is subtype of `T[B]`. Contravariance (`T[-A]`): `A` is subtype of `B` => `T[A]` is **supertype** of `T[B]`. So yes, I guess you've understand it correctly, though no one can read in your head.

Comment: why did someone downvote please? I don't care about points, but the reason my question was bad.

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly right. I would just say it like this:

- Since `String` is a subtype of `AnyRef`, `T[String]` is a subtype of `T[AnyRef]`.
- Since `Integer` is a subtype of `AnyRef`, `T[Integer]` is a subtype of `T[AnyRef]`.

So I can say

```
var s:T[AnyRef] = new T[String]
val i:T[AnyRef] = new T[Integer]
s = i
```

Actually, no I can't say that third line.

I shouldn't be allowed to do that because that likely means `T` is doing something only applicable to `Integer`s that it can now do to `String`s.

So you use type bounding to solve it.

Comment: Good catch. Made the edit. My mom always told me, "You can't slip anything by @dg123." Thanks!